# Populating fields from SO Screen to PO Screen

Tags: acumatica

I need to populate the custom fields from SO Screen to PO Screen when user mark the particular item for PO and PO Source as Dropship. And when user Creates Purchase Order from Actions menu on Sales Order screen.

I have written the code in custom field FieldUpdated event on PO screen POOrderEntryExtension, but it does not show up SO OrderNbr while I try to get the custom field value from SO Screen using BQL as shown below-

```html
protected virtual void POOrder_CustomField_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
 var row = (POOrder)e.Row;

 if (row != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.SOOrderNbr) && row.OrderType == POOrderType.DropShip)
 {
  SOOrder order = PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
       LeftJoin<SOLine,
        On<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOLine.orderType>,
         And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>,
       Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>,
         And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
         And<SOLine.pOSource, Equal<Required<SOLine.pOSource>>>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), row.SOOrderType, row.SOOrderNbr, "D");
  if (order != null)
  {
   e.NewValue = order.CustomFieldFromSO;
  }
 }
}
```

Hence I have written the same code in POOrder_RowPersisting event but now everytime I save the Purchase Order, it overwrites the value from SalesOrder even if I modify.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to default values to those coming over from SOOrder and the SOOrderNbr field gets updated only once on the creation of a purchase order instead of checking the assignment on every persist you can accomplish the same goal with the *POOrder_SOOrderNbr_FieldUpdated* event. Below is sample code for a single custom field coming from SOOrder to POOrder on the "Create Purchase Orders Actions" you can add additional filtering to the SOOrder select as need be.

```
public class SOOrderExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
{
    #region CustomField
    public abstract class usrCustomField
    { }
    [PXDBString(60)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Custom Field")]
    public virtual string UsrCustomField { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class POOrderExtension : PXCacheExtension<POOrder>
{
    #region CustomField
    public abstract class usrCustomField
    { }
    [PXDBString(60)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Custom Field")]
    public virtual string UsrCustomField { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class POOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
{
    public virtual void POOrder_SOOrderNbr_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        POOrder row = e.Row as POOrder;
        if (row != null)
        {
            POOrderExtension rowExt = PXCache<POOrder>.GetExtension<POOrderExtension>(row);

            SOOrder order = PXSelectReadonly<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>, And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>.Select(this.Base, new object[] { row.SOOrderType, row.SOOrderNbr });
            if(order != null)
            {
                SOOrderExtension orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>(order);
                rowExt.UsrCustomField = orderExt.UsrCustomField; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original Sales Order
[image]

Created Purchase Order
[image]

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I think this will work too I am sure.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out, we can check the operation if it is Insert in POOrder_RowPersisting event and that will not overwrite the values. Below is the code sample-

```html
protected virtual void POOrder_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
 if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Insert)
 {
  var row = (POOrder)e.Row;

  if (row != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.SOOrderNbr) && row.OrderType == POOrderType.DropShip)
  {
   SOOrder order = PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
       LeftJoin<SOLine,
        On<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOLine.orderType>,
         And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>,
       Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>,
         And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
         And<SOLine.pOSource, Equal<INReplenishmentSource.dropShipToOrder>>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), row.SOOrderType, row.SOOrderNbr);
   if (order != null)
   {
    row.CustomField = order.CustomFieldFromSO;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This answer breaks Acumatica developer guidelines in regards to what logic lies within which event "Avoid executing additional BQL statements in a RowPersisting event handler. When the RowPersisting event is raised, the associated transaction scope is busy saving the changes, and any other operation performed within this transaction scope may cause performance degradation and deadlocks." ~Acumatica Developer Wiki

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I have tested it and seems your solution is more perfect instead of writing something in RowPersisting event.